# Initialize TypeScript class inside Angular HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript

The question is regarding using TypeScript and Angular (6)

I have a model class:

```
export class DropData {
   private readonly _originType: Component;
   private readonly _originRow: number;
   private readonly _originCol: number;
   private readonly _originComp: number;


   constructor(originType: Component, originRow: number, originCol: number, originComp: number) {
     this._originType = originType;
     this._originRow = originRow;
     this._originCol = originCol;
     this._originComp = originComp;
   }

export class Component {
  id: number;
  component: string;

  constructor(id: number, component: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.component = component;
  }
 }
```

Is there a way to initialize this from a HTML template? I tried the following, which doesn't seem to work:

```
<div mwlDraggable
     [ghostElementTemplate]="dragging"
     [dropData]="new DropData(new PageComponent(component.id, componentManager.getComponentSimpleName(component.id)),rowIndex, colIndex, compIndex)"
     dragActiveClass="drag-active">
     <ng-template
        [appComp]="componentManager.getComponentSimpleName(component.id)"
        [id]="component.id">
     </ng-template>
</div>
```

(***EDIT***: *I omitted the function ' componentManager.getComponentSimpleName(component.id)' it returns a string and works properly*)

***EDIT2***
The stacktrace when accessing the page:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'DropData' at column 5 in [new DropData(new 
PageComponent(component.id, componentManager.getComponentSimpleName(component.id)),rowIndex, colIndex, compIndex)] in ng:///AppModule/PageFoundationComponent.html@80:21 ("    <div mwlDraggable
                 [ghostElementTemplate]="dragging"
                 [ERROR ->][dropData]="new DropData(new 
PageComponent(component.id, componentManager.getComponentSimpleName(comp"): ng:///AppModule/PageFoundationComponent.html@80:21
```

Comment: I'm going to frame challenge this and suggest that that kind of code has no place in a template. Its also worth checking that the template is your problem by running it somewhere else. That being said, your question omitted *what* wasn't working. Please specify what seems to be going wrong (error messages, etc.)

Comment: Good point, I've added the stacktrace which is thrown when accessing the page. Futhermore can you please elaborate on the point why this code should have no place in a template?

Comment: Posted that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates don't have immediate access to globals.

You basically can't access anything in a template that's not a property on the component. So in this case, your component would need:

```
public DropData: any = DropData;
```

This is similar to how you access an enum in a template. You also will have a similar problem with `componentManager`. The fact that you would need to do this kind of thing speaks to why having such code in a template is a poor choice. Templates represent *how a component's data is displayed*. The component itself is responsible for creating/fetching/providing that data.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for elaborating. Professionally I work with Java and at times the Angular / TypeScript platform confuses me. I will then rethink the architecture of my app.